# Pathlib loop only through subdirs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following directory structure

```
mkdir -p joe/{0,1}
mkdir -p john/0

tree 
.
├── joe
│   ├── 0
│   └── 1
└── john
    └── 0
```

And I want to call a program for each entry, in this case the program should be called 3 times, for `program joe/0`, `program joe/1` and `program john/0`

How can I do this in python3 using the new Pathlib?

EDIT: must be the relative path, `program dir/subdir` only

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just found my own answer in case someone else need

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(os.path.expanduser("~"))

for p in home.glob('*/*'):
  print(p.relative_to(home))
```